# Describe permissions of a resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have create a stack, in there we create a lambda, execute some code from SDK, access to s3, write to dynamo and some other stuff, the problem now is that we are trying to deploy to a different account/region that we never deploy again, but now we are facing a lot of issues related to permissions, some of them my team already see them and are properly documented, but other cases, other teams may be facing those errors and we do not have that context, we try to go one by one as they appears but is something painful and my question is if there is a way to describe/analyze the policies that the rol that I assume has in order to execute that stack before the provisioning or how I can figure out which permission my resource needs? or basically it is go throughout all permission one by one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd really like something like this to exist but I do not foresee a reliable one being developed anytime soon. However, since I've been down that road myself I would suggest you something a bit more manageable.

**[AWS CloudFormation service role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-iam-servicerole.html)** allows you to pass a role with greater permissions than the one gave to a normal user. In a nutshell, you must first create a role with some decently large permissions or even administrative permissions. Then you need to allow normal users to perform the `iam:PassRole` action for that resource (the role). Lastly, when you deploy a CloudFormation stack, make sure you specify the role you created as the "service role" in the stack options.

From a security standpoint there is pros and cons to both using a service role or giving a lot of different permissions to normal users. You have to assess for yourself if it's a risk you can manage.